# When to set Windows VERSIONINFO PrivateBuild?

Tags: windows, resources, versioninfo

When should I set the `PrivateBuild` flag in Windows `VERSIONINFO` resource? The [Microsoft docs say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28v=vs8.5%29) that I need to use it in the following case:

> "File was not built using standard release procedures. If this value is given, the 
>   StringFileInfo block must contain a PrivateBuild string."

For example, I ship a custom build of Python with some modifications, but the file name stays `python27.dll`. Should I mark it as private build?

Comment: I'd say yes if you think you or your users would be interested into knowing it's a private build...